# ionic erro ao start app

Tags: node.js, ionic

Estou iniciando meus estudos com ionic v2.
Atualizei a versão do ionic para a v2 porem quando rodo o comando `ionic start wiltonfinances blank --v2` e exibida uma mensagem de erro.

Veja as informações exibidas no console :

**MINGW64**

```
wilton@WILTONPROCOPIO MINGW64  /c/projetocordova (master) 
$ ionic start wiltonfinances blank --v2 

One awesome Ionic app coming right up... 

Creating Ionic app in folder C:\projetocordova\wiltonfinances based on blank project 

Downloading: https://github.com/driftycolionic2-app-base/archive/master.zip 

Downloading: https://github.com/driftyco/ionic2-starter-blank/archive/master.zip 

Installing npm packages... 

Unable to run spawn commandError: spawn npm ENOENT (CLI v2.0.0-beta.23) 

Your system information:

Cordova CLI: 4.2.0 
Gulp version: CLI version 3.9.0 
Gulp local: 
Ionic CLI Version: 2.0.0-beta.23 
Ionic App Lib Version: 2.0.0-beta.13
OS: 
Node Version: v4.4.1
```

**Erro**

> Unable to run spawn commandError: spawn npm ENOENT (CLI
>   v2.0.0-beta.23)

Você também pode visualizar mensagem de erro clicando [aqui](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SRZ2E.png).

Comment: Seja bem vindo ao SO. Procure complementar suas questões de forma a facilitar o entendimento dos outros. Por exemplo, com a versão anterior funcionava?

Comment: Tens o node.js instalado?

Comment: Seja bem-vindo, wilton. Evite o uso de imagens para descrever erros. É preferível que cole o erro na pergunta para facilitar a busca de pessoas que venham a ter o mesmo erro no futuro. Se for usar uma imagem, não omita a descrição da imagem.

Comment: wilton existem soluções online em que você pode converter  "imagem em texto"  que podem melhorar o enunciado das perguntas,  eu gosto e utilizei para editar o seu tópico a solução disponibilizada nesse site  http://www.onlineocr.net/

Comment: Tem alguma razão para utilizar estas versões "antigas"?

Answer (score 0):

Bom dia,

neste link [ENOENT error when doing ionic start](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36238862/enoent-error-when-doing-ionic-start)

aparentemente ocorre o mesmo erro, segundo a resposta aceita pelo autor, a solução foi esta:

"Eu tenho exatamente o mesmo problema. Funcionou em beta 22.

Revertendo para a versão beta anterior resolveu o problema:

install npm -g ionic@2.0.0-beta.22 "

Espero ter ajudado!